# setRowHeight in an especial row pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I used pandastable to print a table on tkinter GUI, but when the data printed I got in front Text Crowded in cell issue as we can see in bellow picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIU32.png)

This is my try:

```
pt.setRowHeight(70)
```

This is the result which I got it :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS32L.png)

its set row height in all rows table instead I want to set it in an especial row.
Any  help please!
Thank you in advance!
Kind regards